# Why i am getting InnoDB deadlock error? "Deadlock found when trying to get lock"

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have the InnoDB table in MySQL.
I got the error
"Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

The query is a simple DELETE query. There is no transaction.

The query is like
"DELETE FROM mylogs WHERE userid=178487 AND logdate<'2021-03-12 15:13:32'"

What can be the reason i got this error? Maybe there were some other SELECT or INSERT or DELETE queries parallel, but i do not know. No more errors.

What can be the reason of this error and how i can prevent?

There is the index structure .

[image]

There i the info about the last deadlock
[image]

There is the result of "show create table logs;"
[image]

Comment: Have you run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` and checked the section on latest deadlock error? It should give you more detail.

Comment: Do you have a composite index `INDEX(userid, logdate)`, in that order?

Comment: No. There are no composite indexes. Only single indexes on both these columns.

Comment: I added the report from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G in the post

Comment: Could you provide the result of `show create table logs` to give more info.

Comment: It seems that you perform two the same delete at the same time.

Comment: I have attached the "show create table logs;" . And yes, it is most probably i have 2 parallel DELETE operations. Can t be the reason? How to prevent a deadlock in such case?